# Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debuggger named xx. The connection with the remote endpoint was terminated

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service, remote-debugging

I try to remote debug an Azure app, but when trying to attach the debugger (manually or automatically with the cloud explorer) I get the error:

> Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debuggger
>   named xx. The connection with the remote endpoint was terminated.

In the Event Viewer of the apps server I get the event:

> Msvsmon was unable to start a server named '127.0.0.1:50119'. The
>   following error occurred: An instance of the remote debugger is
>   already running on this computer, or another process is already bound
>   to the specified TCP/IP port.  View Msvsmon's help for more
>   information. 08005E80

What did I already do:

- Delete the web app and publishing it again (debug mode)
- Turned off the firewall on my development machine
- Checked that the Remote Debugging on the azure app is set to ON in the portal and has the correct Remote Visual Studio version (2015 update 2 in my case)
- I can remote debug a UWP app on another machine on my LAN

So how can I debug my webapp?

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution for this? Maybe a port is no longer open. I'm just now experiencing this, but it worked just a few hours ago. Incredibly frustrating.

Comment: The problem goes away and reappears without any noticible cause. So I'm still stuck with this issue from time to time.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I think I may have found a working solution: Just install the latest Azure SDK (2.9 as of this comment). Doing so installed a "Cloud Explorer" tab in VS2015, which seems to be an upgraded version of Server Explorer. For whatever reason, attaching the debugger via this window seems to work flawlessly. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm getting this issue after having attached the debugger via Cloud Explorer - seemed to work first time (but hit an exception in code). Has not worked after that, despite republishing web app and restarting VS.